# Print array in field value

Tags: entities

I have created a custom form in form field following code is there.

```
 $form['display_result'] = array(
   '#title' => 'Result' ,
   '#type' => 'textarea',
   '#value' => !empty($dval) ? $dval : null,
   '#default values' => '',
 )
```

Problem is $dval is array which includes following code:

```
    stdClass Object
(
    [to] => Tove
    [from] => Jani
    [heading] => Reminder
    [body] => Don't forget me this weekend!
)
```

I am getting following warning:

> Warning: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in check_plain() (line 1571 of /var/www/html/D7/includes/bootstrap.inc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's recommended to use `#default_value` instead of `#value`.

You have to use property of object instead of whole object. For example `$dval->body`.

```
$form['display_result'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Result'),
    '#type' => 'textarea',
    '#default_value' => !empty($dval->body) ? $dval->body : '',
  );
```

Comment: But i want to populate whole array instead of $dval->body. Just like we print_r($dval).

Comment: Pass TRUE to `print_r` function, is set to true, print_r will return its output, instead of printing it.
`'#default_value' => print_r($dval, TRUE),`